# How to limit my decimal value to 2 places on my <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, decimal

I'm making a query to my database to return a value of double precision. This value in my database goes up to 17 decimal places but I only want to display 2 decimal places on the web page.

This is my html with the table. The value of the decimal goes into the {{savings_percent}}

```
 <table class="table text-light text-end">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                
                                                <th scope="col">CHW</th>
                                       
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="text-end">
                                            <tr id="decimal">
                                                <th scope="row">%</th>
                                                {{#with chw}}
                                                <td class='rounded'>{{savings_percent}}</td>
                                                {{/with}}
                                            
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

This is how I'm trying to grab the  value, convert it to decimal and then give it a fixed number of two decimals. The console is giving me $(...).val(...).toFixed is not a function.
Does anyone have a solution on how I can fix this?

```
let decimal = parseFloat($("#decimal .rounded").text())
    
    window.onload = () => {

        $('.rounded').val(decimal).toFixed(2)

        console.log(decimal)   
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val()` is only for form controls

I would use `text(function)` which gives you the current text to do what you need to before returning modifications

```
$('.rounded').text(function(i,curr){
    return parseFloat(curr).toFixed(2)
})
```

Comment: This worked for my most recent question as well. Thanks!

Comment: I like this function, it offered me a solution to my dynamic table column cell decimal value display.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```js
 $('#decimal').val(decimal.toFixed(2))
```

Call `toFixed` on the number, not on the jQuery object returned by `.val()`.

Comment: `val()` is only for form controls

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use `decimal` as a number somewhere else, there is no need to convert it into a number and then back into a string, just to truncate the unwanted digits. You could simply do:

```js
let decimal = $("#decimal .rounded").text().substring(0, $("#decimal .rounded").text().indexOf('.') + 3);
```

or, to make it more readable:

```js
let decimal = $("#decimal .rounded").text(); // retrieve the numeric string
let truncated = decimal.substring(0, decimal.indexOf('.') + 3) // get the substring from the beginning to the second character after the '.' (included)
```

or you can use a regex:

```js
let decimal = $("#decimal .rounded").text().match(/\d+\.\d{2}/)[0]
```